# I need to display jquery popup only once

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi i am using jquery popup's. I need to display popup's only once on page.For this i used cookies:

```
if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1') {
    //code to display popup
    $.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 30 });
}
```

condition above works for all except below popup:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   if(e.pageY <= 5) {
      // Launch MODAL BOX
      $('#exit_content').modal({onOpen: modalOpen, onClose: simplemodal_close});
   }
});
```

This popup also need to display only once.

Comment: if ($.cookie('test_status') != '1') {
    //code to display popup
    $.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 30 });
}

Comment: Don't you think you should put the condition inside the `mousemove` event ?

Comment: i am not sure is it work?

Comment: Where do you show the popup? inside this `f(e.pageY <= 5) { .... }` ?

Comment: yes inside  if(e.pageY <= 5) {.....}

Answer (score 1):

You should check the cookie's value inside your event, if the value was not `1`, it means that the popup hasn't shown yet and it goes inside the `if` and shows the popup and set the value to `1`. Then next time the cookie is `1` and it never goes inside the `if`, so it never shows the popup again.

So simply you can do this:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   // Check if the cookie's value is not 1
   if(e.pageY <= 5 && $.cookie('test_status') != '1') { 
      // Launch MODAL BOX
      $('#exit_content').modal({onOpen: modalOpen, onClose: simplemodal_close});
      // set the cookie to 1
      $.cookie('test_status', '1', { expires: 30 });
   }
});
```

Comment: @ArunKumar If it helped you can vote the answer up and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this ?

```
 $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
       if(e.pageY <= 5) {

    if ($.cookie('exit_modal') != '1') {
    // Launch MODAL BOX
          $('#exit_content').modal({onOpen: modalOpen, onClose: simplemodal_close});
        //code to display popup
        $.cookie('exit_modal', '1', { expires: 30 });
    }

       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery one() to execute a mouseclick only once. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Then if the cookie is alerady set, don't create the event at all.